# ASP.net VB file upload crashes application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am not a VB developer or an ASP.net developer. But I need to create some simple upload functionality to integrate into an existing application.

aspx file

```
<div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
</form>
</div>
```

aspx.vb file

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Namespace MyApp
    Partial Class uploadPage
        Protected Sub upload_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uploadButton.Click
            If fileUp.HasFile Then
                Try
                    fileUp.SaveAs("C:\Uploads\" & fileUp.FileName)    
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
                End Try
            Else
                Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

When a file is uploaded there is a pause, and then the page is redirected to an error message 'This webpage is not available' and I need to restart IIS. Can anyone give advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Windows error log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba21eeb
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005e98
Faulting process id: 0xa14
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e58b87ac8670
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: cc6db860-517e-11e5-b0b2-001c42dfc404
```

Comment: Looks like you reading this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx , if you so, have you set the permissions on the folder? Also show the error just where it started.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a security problem. Look at the event logs, you might see the error.

Comment: I gave the everyone group on that directory full control. But I will look at the event logs to see if there are any errors thrown.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors coming up under Windows Logs>Application.